# How to get input child value form? VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to VueJS. I need to get child input value from form el. I need to get username & password value when click event trigger and alert it for test.

```
<form id="login-form">
    <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required><br>
    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required><br>
    <input v-on:click="submitLogin" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

    const loginForm = new Vue({
        el: '#login-form',
        methods: {
            submitLogin: function() {
                alert(username + password);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use v-models to achieve this. Look at the code below:

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    // You need to define these variables inside of your data
    username: '',
    password: ''
  },
  methods: {
    submitLogin: function() {
      // Whenever you want to access variables from data, prefix them with 'this.'
      alert(this.username + this.password);
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form id="login-form">
      <!-- Set v-model as an attribute on the input field -->
      <input v-model="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required><br>
      <input v-model="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required><br>
      <input v-on:click="submitLogin" type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</div>
```

> Documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html